# How to create Key-Value Pairs with TStringList in C++Builder 6?

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-6, tstringlist

I want to create key-value pairs in a `TStringList` in a C++Builder 6 VCL application.

I know how to read the Names and Values out, but I can't find a way to create the paired entries that works.

I tried, for example:

```
TStringList *StringList = new TStringList();
StringList->Add("Sydney=2000");
```

`StringList->Names[0]` returns `"Sydney"` but `StringList->Values[0]` returns `""`.

I know this works in CB11, but I can't find a way in BCB6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the named pair correctly (in recent versions, you can use the [`AddPair()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.AddPair) method instead).

The [`Values[]`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Values) property takes a key name, not an index (and always has, so your claim that the code you have shown works in CB11 is incorrect), eg:

```cpp
TStringList *StringList = new TStringList;
StringList->Add("Sydney=2000");
ShowMessage(StringList->Names[0]);         // shows "Sydney"
ShowMessage(StringList->Values["Sydney"]); // shows "2000"
delete StringList;
```

The only reason that using `Values[0]` even compiles at all is because the property takes a `System::String`, and in C++ a `String` can be constructed directly from an integer value (in Delphi, you have to make that conversion explicitly using the `SysUtils.IntToStr()` function).

The [`ValueFromIndex[]`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.ValueFromIndex) property, on the other hand, takes an index, but it wasn't available until Delphi 7 (and thus did not appear in C++Builder until CB2006), eg:

```cpp
TStringList *StringList = new TStringList;
StringList->Add("Sydney=2000");
ShowMessage(StringList->Names[0]);          // shows "Sydney"
ShowMessage(StringList->ValueFromIndex[0]); // shows "2000"
delete StringList;
```

So, because `TStringList` in C++Builder/Delphi 6 did not have the `ValueFromIndex[]` property yet, if you want to access a value by index then you will have to use the `Names[]` property to get the key name needed for the `Values[]` property, eg:

```cpp
TStringList *StringList = new TStringList;
StringList->Add("Sydney=2000");
String name = StringList->Names[0];
ShowMessage(name);                     // shows "Sydney"
ShowMessage(StringList->Values[name]); // shows "2000"
delete StringList;
```

Alternatively, you can extract the value manually (so you don't have to waste time searching the list for a matching name), eg:

```cpp
TStringList *StringList = new TStringList;
StringList->Add("Sydney=2000");
String name = StringList->Names[0];
ShowMessage(name);  // shows "Sydney"
String s = StringList->Strings[0];
String value = s.SubString(name.Length() + 2, MaxInt);
ShowMessage(value); // shows "2000"
delete StringList;
```